# Firebase - Error in Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processFacebookDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am trying to make login with firebase using all Sign in methods using google code [for quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) but I got following error in console.

1. Error
2. App/Gradle
3. Web/Gradle

**Gradle Console Error**

```
    Parsing json file: E:\Git\FireBase All\quickstart-android-master\auth\app\google-services.json
:app:processFacebookDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processFacebookDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

**App/Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {

        // Build variant to include the Facebook Android SDk
        // The Facebook Android SDK has a min SDK version of 15
        facebook {
            minSdkVersion 15
        }

        // Build variant to exclude the Facebook Android SDK
        // Firebase Authentication has a min SDK version of 9
        nofacebook {
            minSdkVersion 9
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

    // Firebase Authentication
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'

    // Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'

    // Facebook Android SDK (only required for Facebook Login)
    // This is only compiled into the 'facebook' variant of this app. You can build
    // a 'nofacebook' variant to test on devices with SDK < 15.
    facebookCompile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'

    // Twitter Android SDK (only required for Twitter Login)
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Web/Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Where have you used `com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth`? Try replacing wherever it is with your package name. Or provide us with your activity(s)

Answer (score 1):

1. got to your app folder check if you have google-services.json
2. if not present you need to download it from firebase
3. open google-services.json then make sure the package name is as follows `"package_name": "com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth"`